# Trying to dynamically show elements that are hidden in the stylesheet with JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm writing a card game in JS that uses an onclick event to decide who goes first. I'm trying to make every other element (contained within 2 divs) hidden until this has happened.

I've tried setting these divs as `display:none` in the CSS, then using `x.style.display = 'block'` in the Javascript to make them visible:

```js
let firstGoChosen = 0;

function hideShow() {
  let div1 = document.getElementById('divvy1');
  let div2 = document.getElementById('divvy2');
  if (firstGoChosen === 1) {
    div1.style.display = 'block';
    div2.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

The function called by the onclick event sets `firstGoChosen = 1`

I've also tried this using `visibility:hidden` but neither have worked so far.

I'm only using pure JS for this as I'm not learning jQuery yet.
[Here's the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1h9s5oax/) for anybody feeling brave...

Comment: Look at the javascript console you have an error, then take a look at your elements, you didn't use an id, you used a class

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use css class names as id's, that's what is not working. You can fix this by either adding an id

`<div class="divvy1" id="divvy1">`

and continuing to use `getElementById()` or you can look into using [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) which functions a little differently but looks more to be what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Good spot, thanks so much. As a follow-up question, is using the same names for classes and IDs something to avoid?

Comment: Yeah so your classes will typically be applied to multiple elements, whereas an id is specific to one and only one element

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use getElementsByClassName , as you are using class and trying with document.getElementById

document.getElementsByClassName returns array of elements with matching classname i.e divvy1 and divvy2, as there is one element choose first by [0]

```
let div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('divvy1')[0];
let div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('divvy2')[0];
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MGpNoR

Option 2 is to change class to ids and use same javascript code to make work

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure you can do this easily by:

```
document.querySelectorAll(‘.thoseElements:nth-child(even)’)
  .forEach(function (el) {
    el.style.display = ‘none’;
  });
```